# Proof by contradiction that a finite set has elements that must be both paired

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinite-groups

The set A has elements a. For any given element a, there must be an equivalent element b in set B.

For any a and b pair, there must be a element c in C.

For each element in C, there must be an equivalent element in D and for each pair in C and D there must be a element in E. This keeps going, so for each pair there is a pair which needs a pair and so on.

My question is how I describe this mathematically, and how do I prove that the set of all such sets cannot be finite?

Comment: What does "equivalent" mean?  Like literally the same element, or is there some relation lurking here?

Comment: a and b are identical except for their memberships in A and B respectively. c is not, and governs the relationship between a and b, relating them to each other. To give a metaphor, a and b are both children in different classes, with c being a teacher who can tell them apart. c has a twin teacher in a different class, and now you need someone, e, who can tell those two apart, and so on.

Comment: Can different elements in $A$ be paired with the same element of $B$? Similarly can different pairs of $(a, b)$ produce the same element of $C$? Do $A$, $B$ etc have to be finite? Also I don't think the tag [tag:general-topology] is appropriate here.

Comment: "Can different elements in A be paired with the same element of B? " - No, the pairing is exclusive, as is the ab:c relationship. There is a unique c for each a. Great point to clarify. Apologies on the miscategorization. I'll edit that.

Comment: I believe a term that might be applicable is 'vicious infinite regress'.